# typeof variable === "function" is true, but variable still lacks a call signature due to unexpected type merging

Tags: typescript

Pretty much similar to React I want to work with states in a custom library and I currently have the following class:

```js
export abstract class Room<State> {
    protected state: State;

    protected setState<Key extends keyof State>(
        state: ((previousState: Readonly<State>) => Pick<State, Key> | State)
             | (Pick<State, Key> | State)
    ) {
        if (typeof state === "function") {
            // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
            // '((previousState: Readonly<State>) => State | Pick<State, Key>) | (State & Function)'
            // has no compatible call signatures.
            const newState = state(this.state);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

As you can see in the comment Typescript complains that state lacks a call signature although I expected to be able to distinguish both types of the state argument. Surprisingly enough when removing the final `| State` at the end of the `state` type it works, however Intellisense in VS Code no longer offers key completion in lines such as `this.setState({ foo: 1 });`.

Why is Typescript merging the second type of `state` to `State & Function`? Is it possible to safely rewrite this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, there's a few thing's going on here firstly the extra brackets there are doing nothing because unions are commutative meaning A | (B | C) is the same as (A | B) | C basically the brackets mean nothing, secondly to get around the function problem just write typeof state !== "object" means you get rid of 2/3 from the union and are just left with the function. Hope this helps

```
export abstract class Room<State extends object> {
    protected state: State = "" as any;

    protected setState<Key extends keyof State>(
        state: ((previousState: Readonly<State>) => Pick<State, Key> | State) | (Pick<State, Key>) | State
    ) {
        if (typeof state !== "object") {
            const newState = state(this.state);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry edit, the reason why it fails is because there is not generic constraint on State meaning when typescript reasons about it generically it can't assume State isn't a function meaning typeof state === "function" could leave you with whatever type State is.

Comment: Is there actually a way to constrain the generic `State` type to something **not** callable? This would most likely solve the problem as well.

Comment: Very interesting, but I wonder why `(typeof state === 'function')` isn't enough to convince TS that state is callable

Comment: @hackape Because we are left with `Function | (State & Function)` wherein State might not be callable by itself.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer I will most likely be considering to replace this with `State extends not Function` and revert to `typeof state === "function"` once Typescript 3.5 comes out. In the meantime this works indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a type guard to help you narrow down the union type to that specific function type.

```
function isFunc(state: any): state is Function {
  return typeof state === "function"
}

// then replace 
if (typeof state === "function") { ... }

// with
if (isFunc(state)) { ... }
```

Comment: Even though this forces `state` to be callable I am curious what will happen if the generic type `State` (erroneously) happens to be a function itself?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic The possibility of `State` can be either callable or non-callable is exactly why TS complains in your example. But honestly, this is over cautious, it looks more like a bug to me. I've seen other weird behavior when generic type param get involved. TS is basically saying "I'm not sure about anything, you know, it's a generic type".

Comment: With Typescript 3.5 there will be negated types. I can just assume that I'll be able to write `<State extends not Function>` as a proper constraint, not as of now unfortunately.